# Golang blog slices and internals

Tags: go

```
// Filter returns a new slice holding only
// the elements of s that satisfy f()
func Filter(s []int, fn func(int) bool) []int {
    var p []int // == nil
    for _, v := range s {
        if fn(v) {
            p = append(p, v)
        }
    }
    return p
}
```

I have no i idea how to use this function, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/Asc4v08wDO

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Filter returns a new slice holding only
// the elements of s that satisfy f()
func Filter(s []int, fn func(int) bool) []int {
    var p []int // == nil
    for _, v := range s {
        if fn(v) {
            p = append(p, v)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func odd(i int) bool {
    return i%2 != 0
}

func even(i int) bool {
    return !odd(i)
}

func main() {
    v := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    fmt.Println(Filter(v, odd))
    fmt.Println(Filter(v, even))
}
```

Comment: this helped me, i was a bit confused.